# Make WAF Rules Exempt For an IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-waf

I enabled WAF for my Elastic Beanstalk load balancer. There is some rule that is causing it to block certain admin functionality.

Is there some way that I can make my IP exempt from these rules? Thanks!!

Comment: Hi. "There is some rule" is not very specific. Could you provide more details - which rule, what is its current setting, why it does not work?

Comment: Thanks for the response Marcin! I say "some rule", because I am unfortunately not sure which rule is causing it. But what is happening is that I am trying to upload a large JSON text.

Comment: No problem, but I won't be able to assist much here.  Maybe it would be useful to read latest aws white paper [Guidelines for Implementing AWS WAF](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/guidelines-implementing-aws-waf.pdf). This may help you better setup your WAF.

Comment: I will read over this and get back to you. Thanks so much Marcin!

Comment: No problem. Hopefully it will work out. I assume that without WAF, everthing already works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you set up the WAF in Elasticbeanstalk, but here is the to way to allow some IP for a particular endpoint.

- Create IP matched condition
- Go to WAF and define a rule with IP matched condition that we created on step 1.

[image]

Specify IP matched condition

[image]

For path path filter create another condition that check path in the `URI`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Where do I specify the particular endpoint to be secured by ip?

Comment: The endpoint should be the LB that is integrated with WAF, so any request route to LB will look for IP matched condition

Comment: I see, I am looking to restrict access to one endpoint `/admin`. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: You need two condition, one for IP set the contain the IP and other the container the path, if both are true the allow the request deny otherwise, answer updated so this check `if IP is this and path is admin then allow`

Comment: Actually, quick question: do I have to make a rule that makes it default blocked and then add this rule to allow my ip?

Comment: Yes you can make all block in rule setting as a default action